# Server 2012 Active Directory Password policy

Tags: active-directory, subdomain

For our development environment, I have an AD domain `intra.contoso.com` on a Win 2008 R2 server, with mostly default settings set. The password policy prohibits the use of passwords with less than 5 chars, but allows for all-lowercase names (so the password "password" is allowed).

Yesterday, I had to add a subdomain to test our application in a domain/subdomain setting. So I

- took a Win 2012 server with IIS and SQLExpress installed,
- installed the role "ADDS",
- promoted the server to DC,
- for the AD sub domain `sub.intra.contoso.com`

Now I am trying to create at least one user in said subdomain, with which I want to login from my test machine.

So, from server manager, I open "Active Directory Users and Computers".

I only find the subdomain, not the main AD domain. Is this correct?

Then I go into Users and click "New" form context menu.
I enter username and password, but even a sixteen-digit password with uppercase, numbers and special chars is not allowed by password policy.

Creating a user with account disabled works.

How can I create a user with which I will be able to login?

Comment: Have you promoted the sub domain DC as such? Or have you created a new forest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdomain has it's own password policy, you need to change this as well.
A password which always works for testing purposes is something like WeLcOmE123$!, try this.
Also, windows can be bitchy about passwords which have anything from your username in them.